# How do I change these if-else statements to nested if-else statements?

Tags: java

```
package pa3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RhymingWords
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        System.out.println("Enter three strings of length at least 2: ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        String first = stdin.next();
        String second = stdin.next();
        String third = stdin.next();

        System.out.println(first + " " + second+ " " + third);

        if(first.substring(first.length()-1 , first.length()).equals(second.substring(first.length()-1 , second.length())))
    {
        System.out.println(first + " and " + second + " ryhme");

        if(first.substring(first.length()-1 , first.length()).equals(third.substring(first.length()-1 , third.length())))
        {
            System.out.println("All words ryhme");
        }
    }

    else if(first.substring(first.length()-1 , first.length()).equals(third.substring(first.length()-1 , third.length())))
    {
        System.out.println(first + " and " + third + " ryhme");
    }

        else if(first.substring(first.length()-1 , first.length()).equals(third.substring(first.length()-1 , third.length())))
        {
            System.out.println(first + " and " + third + " ryhme");
        }

        else if(second.substring(second.length()-1 , second.length()).equals(third.substring(second.length()-1 , third.length())))
        {
            System.out.println(second + " and " + third + " ryhme");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No ryhming words");
        }




    }

}
```

My assignment requires me to use nested if-else statements for this Java program without using any boolean operators. I am wondering how I am to go about that as I have the program working. Also how would I add a statement that checks if all words rhyme? My professor wants us to use the following operators.

```
.length()
.substring() 
.charAt()
.equals()
```

The question below:
Write a program named RhymingWords that prompts the user to enter 3 words of length at least 2 and output all the words that rhyme. If none of the words rhyme, then the program outputs “No rhyming words". Your program does not have to check for input validation. You may assume that the user always enters words of length at least 2. Your program must use nested if-else statements and should not use boolean operators.

Comment: Checking if words rhyme is going to be tough, unless you have a dictionary that just by brute strength converts the English spelling to a canonicalized, IPA-or-similar form. See http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html for some examples of just how impossible it'll be to check for rhyming based just on the English spelling. And that doesn't even account for regional accents! Hopefully your teacher has defined what the acceptable definition of "rhyming" is for your assignment.

Comment: Yes he did my bad, words are considered to rhyme if the last two letters in the word are the same. For example Cat and Hat..

Comment: I'd make a method called rhymes(String one, String two) and call it three times, though that doesn't make it nested.

Comment: @BrianPipa the question doesn't allow for boolean operators to be used (which seems to indicate no custom functions)

Comment: @MikeGoedken do you have the actual text of the question that you can put into the question? It is hard to determine exactly what is needed from what you posted.

Comment: @yitzih the rhymes() method wouldn't need boolean operators, neither would calling it

Comment: I added the text of the question in my question

Comment: You have 3 things to compare against each other, resulting in 3 comparisons. Consider what you are going to compare, and consider how you place the if's. Do it on paper and think. We cannot do that for you.

Comment: @JoopEggen if I use the same conditions I cannot come to a conclusion about how to add the ifs into a nest because if one of the statements is true I don't see how it would affect the other comparisons?

Comment: If A rhymes with B and B with C then C rhymes with B. If A does not rhyme with B and A does not rhyme with C then B and C might still rhyme. The latter would be an inner nesting. So play with positive and negative conditions.

Comment: @JoopEggen I edited my code, I got "All words rhyme" now, thank you